# MKMapView not rendering tiles on 10.10 b3

Tags: macos, mkmapview, mapkit, osx-yosemite

I'm doing the bare minimum here. Creating a cocoa app project, adding a MKMapView to the View Controller, and linking the MapKit framework. When I run the app, the control shows but is not rendering any tiles no matter the zoom level. Everything else works. I can see user location, set coords/regions, read them back, etc... It's just not rendering the tiles. It does show the grid that is loaded before the tiles are cached. Am I overlooking something? This is all that you need to do on iOS.

Comment: Okay, it looks like on OSX you need to have an entitlement to render the map. Go to the project capabilities and toggle map to on. Set up your entitlements then it will render.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at the debugger window. Is there something like

"Your Application has attempted to access the Map Kit API. You cannot access this API without an entitlement. You may receive an entitlement from the Mac Developer Program for use by you only with your Mac App Store Apps. For more information about Apple's Mac Developer Program, please visit developer.apple.com."

Then you have to add your developer account to your project.